# Function sum with HQL language

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

I have a question (sorry about my English, I'm learning)! 
I searched everywhere for how to use the command `sum(column)` with `HQL` hibernate language, but I can't find anything!

I can do it with `SQL` language. Example:

```
SELECT sum(Column) FROM tablethatIwantthevalues;
```

but not with HQL Hibernate!

Comment: that should work, HQL has sum function... can you show us error you get when you run this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation functions in HQL as well as in SQL, take a look at the Hibernate Query Language Manual: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-aggregation

Comment: OK, Thank for your time!

Answer (score 4):

**You can use same query as SQL, try below solution :**

```
Session s = OptimazPoolM.getSessionFactory().openSession();
String sumHql = "SELECT SUM(salary) FROM employees WHERE idemployee = 31";
Query sumQuery = s.createQuery(sumHql);
System.out.println(sumQuery.list().get(0));
```